# Why doesn't LO/OOo look completely native?

Tags: themes, gtk, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I am not talking about the Win 98 look, but even with the gnome-integration installed buttons look a bit weird and there are sometimes black lines where there shouldn't be any. Why?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the line behind 'basic fonts (Western) at the top?

Comment: He means around the buttons, there is a lighter grey square surrounding the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be improved in LibO 3.4 --see this before-n-after screenshot: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=42337

Answer (score 7):

It's not using the standard GTK-toolkit - I think it has its own kit... The differences are subtle and many people doesn't seem to notice. But I think it's butt-ugly :/

Even with `openoffice.org-gtk` and `openoffice.org-gnome`
installed.

You can try with a different theme in ubuntu to remove thick black lines though. It's an Ambience glitch.

Comment: Do you know how hard it would be to fix these bugs or move to the standard-GTK?

Comment: This answer is a bit wrong, as it does use gtk, just indirectly. The toolkit is called VCL, and it tries to mimic gtk, so it respects gtk themes, but it's imperfect (very).

Comment: @Roland, I'm also interested in @Toxicbits' problem - how difficult would it be for LO to directly use GTK+?

Comment: I'm not a LO developer, but to my knowledge at this point it would take a *lot* of work, because libreoffice still has a long way to go to free itself of its OOo past

Answer (score 1):

install openoffice.org-gtk and openoffice.org-gnome packages

`sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-gtk openoffice.org-gnome`

Comment: I have them installed, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To make LibreOffice look and feel in a Gnome setting copy and paste this command into the Terminal.

**sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gnome**